# Setting nativeElement.scrollTop is not working, to scroll to bottom of div

Tags: html, angular

I have this code in angular application

*html*:

```
<input type="button" value="Add" (click)="addItems()" />
<div id="messageContainer" style="width:200px; height:300px; overflow-y:scroll;" #scrollMe >
  <div *ngFor="let i of items">
    {{i}}
  </div>
</div>
```

*component.ts*:

```
items: string[] = [];
count = 20;

@ViewChild('scrollMe') private scrollContainer: ElementRef;

ngOnInit() {
    this.addInitialItems();
}

addItems() {
    const currentPosition = this.scrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollTop;

    this.items.unshift(this.count.toString());
    this.count++;

    this.scrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollTop = currentPosition;
 }

addInitialItems() {
    for (let i = 0; i <= this.count - 1; i++) {
        this.items.unshift(i.toString());
    }

    // this is not working
    this.scrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.scrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollHeight; 
}
```

Initially messageContainer div should be filled with multiple items, with div scrolled to bottom, once user click an Add button it will add an item to the top of the messegaes list and should maintain the scroll position.

Retaining scroll position is done with

```
const currentPosition = this.scrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollTop;
//add new item
this.scrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollTop = currentPosition;
```

But, initial scrolling to bottom of div is not working,

```
this.scrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.scrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
```

`scrollTop` value is 0 even after setting it, 
How to get this scrolled to bottom of the div initially?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@ViewChild objects are not fully defined until the 'ngAfterViewInit' lifecycle hook. Try moving your method call to that hook.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.addInitialItems();
}
```

Something else you might want to try is binding to scrollTop directly in the template, so you won't have to access the nativeElement at all.

```
<input type="button" value="Add" (click)="addItems()" />
<div id="messageContainer" style="width:200px; height:300px; overflow-y:scroll;"  [scrollTop]="myScrollVariable">
  <div *ngFor="let i of items">
    {{i}}
  </div>
</div>
```

In your component you could then simply write something like

```
this.myScrollVariable = currentPosition;
```

Instead of modifying the DOM element directly. Granted, if you wanted to initialize the scroll to the scrollHeight, you'd probably still need to use ViewChild to access the nativeElement and get that attribute (although personally, I would just initialize scrollTop to some absurdly high number like 99999999, anything greater than scrollHeight will be the same as the exact scrollHeight).

If moving the method call to ngAfterViewInit doesn't work, try setting scrollTop inside a setTimeout function. Sometimes the Angular change detector is weird about picking up changes to the native DOM and as a workaround you can escape the change outside the regular angular event loop with a timeout.

```
setTimeout(()=>{ this.scrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollTop = whatever; },1)
```

Comment: No need of setTimeout. just do only part of setting scrollTop in ngAfterViewInit. Setting initial model values do in ngOnInit/constructor. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5pm6ks?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: You're very likely right, but certain DOM attributes / methods are finnicky in Angular and occasionally I have to put them in a timeout so they'll change consistently ( .focus() comes to mind)

Answer (score 0):

To build off the accepted answer, you can pretty elegantly set a div to start scrolling at the bottom using template variables:

```html
<div class="overflow-scroll" #scrollContainer [scrollTop]="scrollContainer.scrollHeight">
<!-- tall/wide content -->
</div>
```